# T-SQL :: how to remove CONVERT_IMPLICIT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-performance, query-performance, implicit-conversion

Pinal Dave posted a [query](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/01/29/find-all-queries-with-implicit-conversion-in-sql-server-interview-question-of-the-week-107/) that we can use to find the most polluting implicit conversion. The query works very well and in fact I found a very polluting one:

```
SUM(-[Quantité] * [Conditionnement]) AS QteVendueUQB,
```

This horror is:

1. Taking [Quantité] which has data type `MONEY`
2. Taking [Conditionnement] which has data type `SMALLINT`
3. Multiplying them together

The table looks like this:

[image]

Is there a better way to multiply these two values?

Comment: If the data types are different, then one of them *will* be implicitly converted using data type precedence. There is no way round that. It is by design, and intended. If you don't want implicit conversion, don't use different data types for data that will interact with each other.

Comment: Have you, however, tried explicitly converting one of the columns and seeing that improves performance? I wouldn't, however, personally expect an implicit conversion in a `SUM` to be particularly expensive.

Comment: @Larnu, thank you for your reply. Actually, that is a good feedback. I will try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Larnu wrote in the comment:

> If the data types are different, then one of them will be implicitly
> converted using data type precedence. There is no way round that. It
> is by design, and intended. If you don't want implicit conversion,
> don't use different data types for data that will interact with each
> other.